# Passing attribute from AWS Connect to Lambda using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Stuck on a single step and doc searching isn't helping...

In Connect I have:

1. Store customer input : "What's your age?"
2. Set contact attribute: age -> system -> stored customer input

I know the above works because I've had a Play Prompt read back the attribute.

I want Lambda to handle somethings with the age. I setup a function, I attached it to the Connect instance. I added it to the flow with a simple value pair response and that works (the Play Prompt plays back the non-dynamic response from Lambda).

When I try to make it dynamic breaks.

My understanding is that I should be able to get to this attribute in Lambda by using the passed JSON.... so I'm doing this:

age = event["Details"]["ContactData"]["Attributes"]["age"]

Connect starts saying it has trouble accessing the attribute and ends the call. What am I doing wrong? The rest of the Python code is fine because if I hard set age (age = 24) the code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong my code as it pertains to the lambda / connect integration... it was with something that was just causing an error. I started monitoring the function in cloudwatch and that helped!